# How to use Java Exchanger?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to test out the functions of an exchanger, where I can create some data in a thread, and then transfer it to another thread concurrently. I was hoping the exchanger would do this. The exchange method used in a thread is supposed to go into a waiting state where it waits for another thread to be at this state, and then exchanges information. However, all of my threads just keep waiting forever and never interact. How is this possible? If they are waiting for each other then shouldn't they continue with the action and go to the next line? Thanks for any advice on this.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;

class CustomThread extends Thread {

    private Exchanger<Integer> exchange = new Exchanger<>();

    CustomThread() {

    }


    private void testExchanger() throws InterruptedException {
        Random r = new Random();
        int sendx = r.nextInt(1000);
        int recievex = exchange.exchange(sendx);
        System.out.println(currentThread().getId() + " recieved " + recievex);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            testExchanger();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Thread[] threads = new Thread[6];
                for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                    threads[i] = new CustomThread();
                    threads[i].start();
                }

                for (Thread thread : threads) {
                    try {
                        thread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }




            }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```java
private Exchanger<Integer> exchange = new Exchanger<>();
```

to this

```java
private static Exchanger<Integer> exchange = new Exchanger<>();
```

**Explanation:**
Each of your thread creates a separate exchanger. Making it static will cause that the instance of an `Exchanger` will be shared between the threads.

Comment: damn, I'm sorry for wasting your time with this question, what a stupid mistake. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries :). You could also pass the instance of the `Exchanger` via constructor of your thread

Comment: Ah I see, gotcha!